# Read excel column using Python code(in Linux) and get formula values

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, xlrd, xlwt, xlsxwriter

I have a `pandas` dataframe that looks like this:

```
A    B    C
1    2    =A2+B2
3    4    =A3+B3
```

I write this to an Excel file using xlsxwriter in Python and convert the data frame to Excel.  Now, when I read the Excel from Python, I get `0.0` as the value for `C2` and not `3` (`=A2+B2`).  However, if I open Excel manually, the formulas are evaluated and has '3' in 'C2'. So the problem occurs while reading from code.

Is there a way in Python to read Excel columns with formulas as values?

Answer (score 2):

*So the problem is while reading from code.*

Not really.

The issue is that XlxsWriter doesn't write the value of a formula to an Excel file. From the [XlsxWriter FAQ](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/bugs.html#formula-results-displaying-as-zero-in-non-excel-applications):

> **Formula results displaying as zero in non-Excel applications**
>
> Due to wide range of possible formulas and interdependencies between them XlsxWriter doesn’t, and realistically cannot, calculate the result of a formula when it is written to an XLSX file. Instead, it stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened.
>
> This is the method recommended in the Excel documentation and in general it works fine with spreadsheet applications. However, applications that don’t have a facility to calculate formulas, such as Excel Viewer, or several mobile applications, will only display the 0 results.
>
> If required, it is also possible to specify the calculated result of the formula using the optional value parameter in `write_formula()`:
>
> `worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=2+2', num_format, 4)`

Comment: yes you are right. But isn't there a way in python to get the cell formula value from an excel?

Answer (score 1):

I would save the Excel file as a .csv.  Excel should automatically convert all formulae to values.  You can then read the .csv into Python with the usual file methods.

Comment: If i open the excel file manually and save as CSV then i know it works. But if i create a CSV out of excel from within the code, i cannot fetch the value of a formula cell.