# On Linux, use Python to edit excel file that contains formulas and then read the resulting values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, xlwings

So I have an excel file (.xlsx) on a **Linux** machine, and that excel file contains **cells with formulas**. What I would like to do is edit an input cell's value (i.e. not a formula cell, just a regular cell that contains a simple string) and then read the resulting calculated formula values using Python.

I have code that works well on Windows:

1. I can use openpyxl version 3.0.1 to do the initial edit of the excel file, and then save/close. (I use an older version of openpyxl (3.0.1) to avoid corruption of the excel file that happens in openpyxl 3.1.1).
2. Since openpyxl doesn't calculate formula values (it leaves that heavy lifting to excel itself), I use xlwings to have the actual excel application simply open the file and then save/close it to generate the cached formula values that openpyxl can read.
3. I can then again use openpyxl to read the cached formula calculated values of the updated excel file to get what I want.

So that all works well on Windows, but on **Linux**, I'm struggling to find a way to edit an excel file and then **read the resulting calculated results of cells with formulas after the edit of the excel file** (can't use xlwings since it's Windows only since it uses win32com). Is what I want possible with Pandas (I thought Pandas uses openpyxl under the hood)?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read excel column using Python code(in Linux) and get formula values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740329/read-excel-column-using-python-codein-linux-and-get-formula-values)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had read that post before also and the top answer states from the XLSXwriter FAQ that XLSXWriter relies on excel to do the formula calculations, like other python excel modules do : "Due to wide range of possible formulas and interdependencies between them XlsxWriter doesn’t, and realistically cannot, calculate the result of a formula when it is written to an XLSX file. Instead, it stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened."

Comment: So I still need a way to open the excel file on Linux and then save/close it.

Comment: Use OpenOffice / LibreOffice in headless mode to do the calculations for you. Or a library like PyCel.

Comment: Great, thank you Charlie! I was just looking at the Koala library also. I will post this link here which lists several Python libraries that "help calculate the result of an Excel equation within Python, using the functions as defined in an Excel file without the need for Excel to be installed." However I'm not sure which libraries will run on Linux so the reader will need to investigate that:
https://python-tools-for-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/software_calculation.html